# Mysql 0 gets removed when updating info?

Tags: php, mysql

I have  a weird sql problem that i have never encountered and had no luck in google ing. 
on my website. while ordering a product, a user needs to fill a field with their private id, which is saved in database

```
UPDATE bs_users SET passport_id = 01010101011 WHERE id=177
```

but the problem is that in mysql the 0 gets removed for some reason and this is the result I get in database

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6zva.jpg

the type of the field is varchar, with a limit of 50 characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try enclosing the values in quotes

```
UPDATE bs_users SET passport_id = '01010101011' WHERE id = '177'
```

The reason is `01010101011` is an integer, which is parsed as `1010101011`. It is then converted to a string, but the leading 0 is already lost. If you want to keep the leading 0, pass it in as a string, not an integer.And thanks for the explanation by @Joachim Isaksson

Comment: As an explanation, `01010101011` is an integer, which is parsed as `1010101011`. It is then converted to a string, but the leading 0 is already lost. If you want to keep the leading 0, pass it in as a string, not an integer.

Comment: I deserve to lose a few points for a mistake this idiotic, thank you very much sir

Comment: That is exactly correct  @JoachimIsaksson and i have updated the answer with your comment.:-)